# Display the sum of track values in activity gauge inner radius while rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have used Highchart's activity gauge chart in my code. It is working perfectly fine. My **requirement** is that I want to display the sum of all the values of tracks in the inner radius of chart when no track on the chart is hovered.

Here is my function that shows the chart when data is provided to it.

```
        function ShowProgramActivityChart(graphData) {
        var parsedInformation;
        if (graphData == "") {
            parsedInformation = "";
        } else {
            parsedInformation = JSON.parse(graphData);

            for (counter = 0; counter < parsedInformation.activities.length; counter++) {

                var trackData = parsedInformation.activities[counter].data;
                trackData = "[" + trackData + "]";
                trackData = JSON.parse(trackData);
                parsedInformation.activities[counter].data = trackData;
            }
        }
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge',
                height: '401px',
                //height: '110%',
                events: {
                    render: (parsedInformation != "") ? renderIcons : empty
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Activity Report',
                style: {
                    //fontSize: '24px'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px'
                },
                pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}h</span>',
                positioner: function (labelWidth) {
                    return {
                        x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
                        y: (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15
                    };
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            pane: {
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 360,
                background: (parsedInformation == "") ? [] : parsedInformation.tracks
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickPositions: []
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },
            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    linecap: 'round',
                    stickyTracking: false,
                    rounded: true
                }
            },
            series: (parsedInformation == "") ? [] : parsedInformation.activities
        });
        $('#container .highcharts-no-data text').text('No Activity Performed');
    }
```

And the renderIcons function is as follows:

```
 function renderIcons() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        console.log(chart);
        console.log(point);
        chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
        chart.tooltip.hide = function () { console.log() };
    }
```

Here is the image of results I currently have
[image: Current Result]

And I want to set value of the region highlighted in second image.
[image]

After the code provided by @Deep3015, Here are the two functions added in the code.

```
        function BindMouseOutOnInnerRadius() {
        var sum = 0;
        this.chart.series.map(function (item) {
            sum = sum + item.data[0].y
        })
        console.log(sum)
        chart = this.chart;
        if (!chart.lbl) {
            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('', (this.chart.chartWidth - 80) / 2, (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15)
              .attr({
                  padding: 10,
                  r: 10,
              })
              .css({
                  color: '#000',
                  fontSize: 20
              })
              .add();
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart.lbl
              .show()
              .attr({
                  text: '<span style="fontt-size:10px">Activity</span> <br><br>' + sum
              });
        }, 900)
    }
```

and

```
function LoadInnerRadiusValue() {
        var sum = 0;
        this.series.map(function (item) {
            sum = sum + item.data[0].y
        });
        //console.log(sum);
        chart = this;
        if (!chart.lbl) {
            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('', (this.chartWidth - 80) / 2, (this.plotHeight / 2) + 15)
            .attr({
                padding: 10,
                r: 10,
            })
            .css({
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: 20
            })
            .add();
        }
        chart.lbl
            .show()
            .attr({
                text: '<span style="fontt-size:10px">Total Hours</span> <br><br>' + sum + 'h'
            });
    }
```

Here is the load event added

```
                chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge',
                height: '401px',
                //height: '110%',
                events: {
                    render: (parsedInformation != "") ? renderIcons : empty,
                    load: LoadInnerRadiusValue
                }
```

And another series section with mouseout event is added

```
                series: {
                events: {
                    mouseOut: function() { BindMouseOutOnInnerRadius() }
                }
            }
```

When I comment out this code

```
                    formatter: function () {
                    var chart = this.series.chart;
                    if (chart.lbl) {
                        chart.lbl.hide();
                    }
                    return this.series.name + '<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">' + this.y + 'h</span>'
                }
```

provided by @Deep3015. Sum value shows up but mouse out event is not triggered hence the sum value doesn't hide. When I have 'formatter' section in my chart. Sum value in inner radius does not appear.

I appreciate the effort of @Deep3015 for putting me in right direction.

Comment: Add https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve example. mean while check http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/tb147763/

Comment: @Deep3015 It was a great help. I have modified the code provided by you. I still have one problem. Mouseout event defined in series is not triggering.

Comment: Some Improvements check http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/tb147763/1/

Comment: @Deep3015 This is working perfectly fine. There is one effect of it. I'm unable to get the point.color on hovering over tracks. The text shown in the inner radius when hovered used to match the color of the track. Now it's all black :/ I have been looking for a turn around. Do you know the trick for this? =D

Comment: I have found the solution of color problem by removing the formatter function. Thanks @Deep3015. By the there is still some cases where total value overlaps with track values. Have a look into the link you provided
jsfiddle.net/deep3015/tb147763/1.
Thanks again!

Comment: I solved my problem of overlapping text by removing timeout fucntion to display the label. Have a look into this https://jsfiddle.net/bb92/nmhub5zx/3/

Comment: Good you have sort out.I did the same and also formatted the text properly and added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to sort out the overlap on over by using `setTimeout` function inside tooltip formatter function.

[image: Activity]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/tb147763/3/)  demo

Tooltip formatter

```
  tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    followPointer:false,
    hideDelay: 0,
    shadow: false,
    style: {
      fontSize: '16px'
    },
    useHTML:true,
    formatter: function() {
      var chart = this.series.chart;
      setTimeout(()=>{if (chart.lbl) {
        chart.lbl.hide();
      }},1)
      return this.series.name + '<br><span style="font-size:2em; color:'+this.color+';  font-weight: bold">' + this.y + '</span>'
    },

    positioner: function(labelWidth) {
      return {
        x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
        y: (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15
      };
    }
  },
```

PlotOption

```
  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    },
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            var chart = this.series.chart;
            if (chart.lbl) {
              chart.lbl.hide();
              console.log(chart.lbl)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      events: {
        mouseOut: function() {
          let sum = 0;
          this.chart.series.map((el) => {
            sum += el.data[0].y
          })
          chart = this.chart;
          if (!chart.lbl) {
            chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('', (this.chart.chartWidth - 80) / 2, (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15)
              .attr({
                padding: 10,
                r: 10,
              })
              .css({
                color: '#000',
                fontSize: 20
              })
              .add();
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            chart.lbl
              .show()
              .attr({
                text: '<span style="font-size:.8em">Activity</span><br> <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:1.4em;color:#ff9933">' + sum+'</span>',
              });
          }, 0)

        }
      }
    }
  },
```